# Where exactly does the target names of the SFML components lies? How can I change them? (e.g. sfml-graphics, sfml-system, ...)

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I'm currently trying to use cmake to build and link the sfml libraries and it's kind of confusing to me.

(Maybe because of the fact that I'm new to both sfml and cmake)

This is my file structure:

-main.cpp

-build(target build dir)

-include(sfml headers dir)

-CMakeLists.txt(top level cmakelists)

-lib:

---CMakelists.txt

---libsfml-audio.a

---libsfml-graphics.a

---...

---libsfml-network.a

---null.cpp

when I put these two lines in my upper CMakeLists.txt:

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

somehow it build the makefile properly.

But when I try to did it with these lines of code:

(in upper CMakeLists.txt:)

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC sfml_tut)
```

(in lower CMakeLists.txt:)

```
add_library( sfml_tut null.cpp libsfml-graphics.a libsfml-window.a libsfml-system.a )
```

The functions inside main.cpp shows undefined reference.

So my biggest question is that: why does those target names `sfml-graphics`, `sfml-window` works in target_link_libraries? Where are those name specified? Can I change those target names myself? Cuz I can't find where they lies even when using vscode global seraching `sfml-graphics` and others.

And did I use add_library wrongly in my second example? Thanks.

Comment: You will answer all your questions just by  reading the overview of the `target_link_libraries` command  in the official documentation.

Comment: `add_library( sfml_tut null.cpp libsfml-graphics.a ...)` does NOT link to the library `libsfml-graphics.a`. It is `target_link_libraries` call which performs linking.